# when importing requests in pycharm, Import error occurs

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

When importing requests, the following error message occurs.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/moter/PycharmProjects/compsci/alarm_project/get_events.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
  File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead
  File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 199, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 113, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
  File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\utils.py", line 33, in <module>
    from email._parseaddr import quote
  File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
    import time, calendar
  File "C:\Users\moter\PycharmProjects\compsci\alarm_project\calendar.py", line 1, in <module>
    from O365 import Account
  File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\O365\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .account import Account
  File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\O365\account.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .connection import Connection, Protocol, MSGraphProtocol
  File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\O365\connection.py", line 9, in <module>
    from requests import Session
ImportError: cannot import name 'Session' from 'requests' (C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py)
```

CODE:

```
import requests
import sys

print(sys.path)

r = requests.get("https://openweathermap.org/")
print(r.status_code)
```

I have updated requests from both pip and pycharm itself. Furthermore, I have tried different python versions and the error persists. The error does not occur in IDLE however, but still occurs in other IDEs.

Comment: show your code. And full error message starting at word "Traceback". Did you create file `requests.py` ? It could try to import it from your file `requests.py` instead of module `requests`. Does IDLE use the same Python ? You may have two pythons installed and one has correctly installed `requests` and it works and other tools may use anothter Python which has corrupted module `requests` and it doesn't work.

Comment: What version of requests are you using? (Using the shell, `requests.__version__,`); 
are you sure you import the right package and the IDE has the right virtual env/path?

Comment: I have edited so all the code and the traceback is shown. I am using python 3.7 in PyCharm and I have provided the right path to the python3.7 exe. I have tried the code in IDLE using python from the same path and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note these lines in your traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
import time, calendar
File "C:\Users\moter\PycharmProjects\compsci\alarm_project\calendar.py", line 1, in <module>
from O365 import Account
```

You have a file named `calendar.py` which conflicts with something that the `email` module is trying to import. Your file `calendar.py` does then go on to import something from `O365` which ends up trying to import `Session` from `requests`:

```
  from O365 import Account
File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\O365\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  from .account import Account
File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\O365\account.py", line 1, in <module>
  from .connection import Connection, Protocol, MSGraphProtocol
File "C:\Users\moter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\O365\connection.py", line 9, in <module>
  from requests import Session
```

Which ends up being a circular import, caused by the conflicting filename. So simply rename your `calendar.py`, e.g. to `mycalendar.py` and your issue should be solved